# How to take a list of struct value for doing sum

Tags: c

I would like to take all of the initial value from struct to do calculate, but it always show total in 0 to me. It supposed to show me a total value of 21.. Anyone that can help me to fix my program I will be very appreciated. Thank you for reviewing my question.. (Below is my code and text file)

**wbz.txt:**

```
PID00001:Aircon:2
PID00002:Windows:10
PID00003:Pipe:9
```

**My Code:**

```
#define SIZE 100

struct parts
{
    char pid[50], pname[50];
    int initialvalue;
}p[SIZE];

int main()
{
    FILE* f;
    char data[100], pid[50], * s, back;
    int buf = 0, choice, i=0, total=0;
    memset(p, 0, sizeof(p));
    do {
        printf("Which warehouse (1.WBZ | 2.WSL | 3.WAR): ");
        scanf("%d", &choice);

        if (choice == 1)
        { 

            f = fopen("wbz.txt", "r");
            while (fgets(data, sizeof data, f))
            {

                s = strtok(data, ":");
                if (s != NULL)
                {
                    strcpy(p[i].pid, s);
                }
                s = strtok(NULL, ":");
                if (s != NULL)
                {
                    strcpy(p[i].pname, s);
                }
                s = strtok(NULL, ":");
                if (s != NULL)
                {

                    p[i].initialvalue = atoi(s);

                }
                printf("\nParts ID: %s\nParts Name: %s\nParts Quantity: %d\n", p[i].pid, p[i].pname, p[i].initialvalue);


                if (p[i].initialvalue < 10)
                {
                    printf("\n---------------------------------------");
                    printf("\n%s unit is not enough, only %d left\n", p[i].pname, p[i].initialvalue);
                    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
                }
                else
                {
                    printf("\n---------------------------------------");
                    printf("\nThis unit is enough\n");
                    printf("---------------------------------------\n");
                }
                
            }
            if (i > 0)
                p[i].initialvalue += p[i - 1].initialvalue;
            
            if (++i == SIZE)
            {
                break;
            }
            p[i].initialvalue += p[i].initialvalue;
            printf("\nTotal: %d", p[i].initialvalue);

            fclose(f);
        }
        

        printf("\nDo you want to continue (y/n): ");
        getchar();
        scanf("%c", &back);

    } while (back != 'n');
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] with input and output. Try to shrink it by removing unneeded input, like the warehouse. What is the output of `printf("\nParts ID: %s\nParts Name: %s\nParts Quantity: %d\n", p[i].pid, p[i].pname, p[i].initialvalue);`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You update p[i].initialVlue using itself after having incremented i = you add 0 to 0 because the value you add is not yet set :

```
            // update should  be before the ++i and using previous index
            If (i > 0) {p[i].initialvalue += p[i-1].initialvalue;}

            if (++i == SIZE)
            {
                break;
            }
        } // end of while loop here
        // next line is not good so remove it
        //p[i].initialvalue += p[i].initialvalue;

        // i is SIZE here do decrease it
        // to get the last value
        i—
        printf("\nTotal: %d", p[i].initialvalue);
        }
```

Also you should initialise p with 0 before using it :

```
memset(p,0,sizeof(p));
```

Comment: So I will just need to add `if (i > 0) {p[i].initialvalue += p[i-1].initialvalue;}` before the `if (++i == SIZE)` and initialise `memset(p,0,sizeof(p));`?

Comment: @Jayden : yes. The memset to be sure of the contents of initialValue before using it. Then the update should add the previous initialValue but do this before updating i. If you do it after, you may access data out of array.

Comment: Hi, I try to add `if (i > 0) {p[i].initialvalue += p[i-1].initialvalue;}` and initialise `memset(p,0,sizeof(p));` already, but it still show in total 0. I updated my post's code, can you help me check again did I put the code in the wrong line?

Comment: I just saw that you have the ++i outside the while loop. The parts (if I > 0) … and if (++i < SIZE) should be inside the while loop. And also remove the line that I told you was doing nothing. I will update the answer.

Comment: It works, thank you very much for your help... I really appreciated, thank you.